# Why isn't chat integrated within the mobile apps?

Tags: feature-request, chat, ios-app, mobile-web

I'm simply curious as to why there isn't chat integrated within the mobile apps (mainly iOS).

It's fairly annoying to have the app redirect me to Google Chrome (iOS version) every single time I try to open chat on the iPhone (which is often), and I usually have around ~20 to 30 tabs open after I'm done with chatting.

Also, to be honest, there is no support for iOS in the mobile version of the chat.

Some proposals (if possible):

- Add some form of chat integration into the app (for both Android and iOS)

  - It should be integrated by now, instead of a redirect link.
- At least integrate the chat properly for iOS users (it's basically just the webpage, I have to zoom out every time for my message to be rendered properly, and the keyboard blocks out the text)

Comment: The mobile chat works fine in iOS

Answer (score 4):

Why isn't it integrated?

Because someone needs to developer an API for chat, have the app interact with it, design the chat interface for the app and actually code up all of these.

After doing all that, it needs to be tested, deployed and supported. On both platforms.

There's a lot of time and effort for a very small team, who have other features and bug fixes to work on.

Comment: Huh, I thought SE was quite a large team - I mean, it's such a large website.

Comment: The mobile team is very small. Having a lot of users != having a large team ;)

Comment: Ah... well, with such a big site (collection of sites), I thought the team would be much larger - I'm mistaken then.

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp http://stackoverflow.com/company/team#Engineering 50 people on Dev, but only a few for mobile.